Kubernetes Garage CORS Configuration
I have a self-hosted K8 cluster where I deployed an object store using Garage with an Nginx ingress and a MetalLB instance with a local IP.
MetalLB exposes a local IP from the configured pool and I can use that from my computer, while on the same network as the cluster, to send an authorised request with Postman and retrieve objects just fine.
However, when I try to send the same request from my front-end app in JS hosted locally on my pc, predictably, I get blocked by CORS.
I tried allowing as many CORS as possible in the Nginx ingress using annotation following the official documentation, but without success.
My servcie config looks like this:
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: garage
  namespace: garage
  uid: 694c2432-49bc-4e78-9c20-6534b6b99ee0
  resourceVersion: '10569149'
  creationTimestamp: '2024-05-21T12:13:38Z'
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: garage
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: garage
    app.kubernetes.io/version: v1.0.0
    helm.sh/chart: garage-0.5.0
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: garage
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: garage
    metallb.universe.tf/ip-allocated-from-pool: local-pool
...
spec:
  ports:
    - name: s3-api
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3900
      targetPort: 3900
      nodePort: 30590
    - name: s3-web
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3902
      targetPort: 3902
      nodePort: 31928
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: garage
    app.kubernetes.io/name: garage
...
  type: LoadBalancer
  sessionAffinity: None
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
    - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts: true
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - ip: 192.168.1.241

While this is my nginx config:
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: garage-s3-api
  namespace: garage
  uid: 9af7930c-3220-4518-b2f9-88776c34234c
  resourceVersion: '10565074'
  generation: 1
  creationTimestamp: '2024-05-21T12:13:38Z'
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: garage
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: garage
    app.kubernetes.io/version: v1.0.0
    helm.sh/chart: garage-0.5.0
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: 'true'
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: garage
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: garage
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: '*'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: '*'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-expose-headers: '*'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: 'true'
...
spec:
  rules:
    - host: s3.garage.tld
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: garage
                port:
                  number: 3900
    - host: '*.s3.garage.tld'
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: garage
                port:
                  number: 3900
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - ip: 192.168.1.111


I am new to the world of Kubernetes and I think it is safe to say I'm not really sure what I'm doing and I'm hoping to figure it out as I go along, but I am really stuck now.
